# "ECHO is on" is setting in variable

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd

I have a batch file which takes three parameters [log:path], [logok:path], [logerr:path]. The values of the respective parameter is `log:c:\logs\install.log`, `logok:c:\logs\installok.log`, 
`logerr:c:\logs\installerr.log`.

I need to process these 3 parameters and set it on respective variable `log=c:\logs\install.log`, `logok=c:\logs\installok.log`, `logerr=c:\logs\installerr.log` so that I can use them in next step to create a file in those paths.

I have written below script but somehow each variable is printing "ECHO is on". It should actually print the location path. Any idea how to achieve this?

```
    REM PARAMS ARE [LOG:PATH] [LOGOK:PATH] [LOGERR:PATH]
    REM ACCESS WITH '%LOG%', '%LOGOK%' AND '%LOGERR%'

    REM SETUP LOCALIZED ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES FOR THE LOG, LOGOK AND LOGERR PARAMS

    SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
    FOR %%A IN (%*) DO (
    ECHO %%A >> C:\LOGS\TEST1.TXT
        FOR /F "TOKENS=1,2,3 DELIMS=:" %%G IN ("%%A") DO (
          SET %%G=%%H:%%I
        )
    )
    ENDLOCAL

    ECHO %LOG% >> C:\LOGS\TEST2.TXT
    ECHO %LOGOK% >> C:\LOGS\TEST3.TXT
    ECHO %LOGERR% >> C:\LOGS\TEST4.TXT

    START /WAIT MSIEXEC /I "%~DP0SETUP.MSI" /QN

    SET EXIT_CODE=%ERRORLEVEL%


    REM If the instalaltion is successful it should a create installok.log file in 'c:\logs'
       IF %EXIT_CODE% EQU 0 ECHO INSTALLED >> %LOGOK%  
    REM If it fails then it should a create installerr.log file 'c:\logs')
       IF NOT EXIST %LOGOK% ECHO FAILED >> %LOGERR%
```

Output of TEST1.TXT:

```
log:c:\logs\install.log 
logok:c:\logs\installok.log
logerr:c:\logs\installerr.log
```

Output of `TEST1.TXT`,`TEST2.TXT`,`TEST3.TXT`:

```
 ECHO is on.
```

Comment: `Echo is on` means there is no variable. The command end up just being `echo` and echo by itself says whether echo in on or off. `ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
` is turned on and not used. Then you turn off `setlocal` throwing away all variables.

Comment: Great !!. It worked, if I put 'end local' at the end of the script.

Comment: Type `Setlocal /?`, `set /?`, `start /?` (also misused), `for /?`, and `if /?`. Also see https://winsourcecode.blogspot.com/2019/12/command-prompt-cheat-sheet.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
REM PARAMS ARE [LOG:PATH] [LOGOK:PATH] [LOGERR:PATH]
REM ACCESS WITH '%LOG%', '%LOGOK%' AND '%LOGERR%'

REM SETUP LOCALIZED ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES FOR THE LOG, LOGOK AND LOGERR PARAMS

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR %%A IN (%*) DO (
ECHO %%A >> c:\Logs\TEST1.TXT
    FOR /F "TOKENS=1,2,3 DELIMS=:" %%G IN ("%%A") DO (
      SET %%G=%%H:%%I
    )
)

ECHO !LOG! >> c:\LOGS\TEST2.TXT
ECHO !LOGOK! >> c:\LOGS\TEST3.TXT
ECHO !LOGERR! >> c:\LOGS\TEST4.TXT

START /WAIT MSIEXEC /I "%~DP0SETUP.MSI" /QN

SET EXIT_CODE=%ERRORLEVEL%


REM If the instalaltion is successful it should a create installok.log file in 'c:\logs'
   IF %EXIT_CODE% EQU 0 ECHO INSTALLED >> !LOGOK!
REM If it fails then it should a create installerr.log file 'c:\logs')
   IF NOT EXIST !LOGOK! ECHO FAILED >> !LOGERR!
ENDLOCAL
```

Basically this:

- Extends the local scope so that the variables which were assigned inside the `FOR` loop will be available in the rest of the script
- Moves variables to the `!delayed!` variable syntax in order to cause them to be evaluated as late as possible. See [the documentation for "EnableDelayedExpansion"](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) for more details

Note that "`ECHO is on.`" is the output that you get when calling `echo` with no parameters:

```
C:\>type echo_test.bat
echo 
echo %no_such_variable%
C:\>echo_test.bat

C:\>echo
ECHO is on.

C:\>echo
ECHO is on.
```